# Laravel 5.1 customizing the paginator styling

Tags: php, css, pagination, laravel-5.1

Is there a way to customize the paginator view in Laravel 5.1.

I want to add a first and last link in addition to the out of the box previous and next links.

I want to change the previous and next links to display icons instead of text but display text for screen readers.

I want to limit the number of page links to display only 5.

Below is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<ul class="pagination no-margin pull-right">
    <li class="disabled">
        <a href="/">First</a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
        <a href="#">
           <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
           <i class="fa fa-caret-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="/">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/">4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/">5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a href="/">Last</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In instead of

```
$users->render()
```

use

```
@include('pagination', ['paginator' => $users])
```

create `pagination.blade` in views directory

add this code in pagination file

```
@if ($paginator->lastPage() > 1)
  <ul class="pagination">
 <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == 1) ? ' disabled' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{ $paginator->url(1) }}">Previous</a>
</li>
@for ($i = 1; $i <= $paginator->lastPage(); $i++)
    <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == $i) ? ' active' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ $paginator->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a>
    </li>
@endfor
  <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == $paginator->lastPage()) ? ' disabled' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{ $paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()+1) }}" >Next</a>
  </li>
</ul>
@endif
```

you can add your style in this file

get the last page `$paginator->lastPage()` and first page is `1`

Comment: How do you append to links e.g. `{!! $users->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->render() !!}` and how do you calculate a first page and last page?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this file for customizing the paginator styling

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapThreePresenter.php
```